# Why does SWbemServices.ExecQuery return more properties than requested?

Tags: wmi, jscript, wmi-query, wmi-service

I'm getting unexpected results from the below JScript code. The *Index* property is returned even though I've only requested *MACAddress*.

What's going on here?

**JScript:**

```js
var wmi, col, itr, obj;

wmi = GetObject('winmgmts:');
col = wmi.ExecQuery('SELECT MACAddress FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration');
itr = new Enumerator(col);

for (; !itr.atEnd(); itr.moveNext()) {
  obj = itr.item();
  itr = new Enumerator(obj.Properties_)
  for (; !itr.atEnd(); itr.moveNext()) {
    obj = itr.item();
    WSH.echo(obj.name)
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Index
MACAddress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is normal, the WMI always returns (if is present) the key property (a property that uniquely identifies an instance of a class) and the others specified in the WQL sentence.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Are you aware of a *IsKeyProperty* method to determine if the item we've got is a key property?

Comment: You must check the properties qualifiers for that http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566365%28v=vs.85%29.aspx